# ionic capacitor : Error: Not implemented on web

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

After doing the migration from `cordova` to `capacitor`, I get the following error while running `ionic s`

#### Error

```
vendor.js:114293 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Not implemented on web.
Error: Not implemented on web.
    at AppWeb.unimplemented (vendor.js:1941:12)
    at node_modules_capacitor_app_dist_esm_web_js.js:40:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (vendor.js:234184:24)
    at _next (vendor.js:234206:9)
    at vendor.js:234213:7
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:9384:21)
    at vendor.js:234202:12
    at AppWeb.getInfo (node_modules_capacitor_app_dist_esm_web_js.js:41:7)
    at vendor.js:1704:23
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:9124:19)
    at polyfills.js:9019:9
    at polyfills.js:9036:25
    at rejected (vendor.js:67367:89)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:8112:158)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:136063:25)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills.js:8112:46)
    at Zone.run (polyfills.js:7853:35)
    at polyfills.js:9197:28
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:8145:171)
```

Does somebody knows what I'm missing?

Comment: this can't be mentioned as general error, so perhaps if u could mention the general steps you did to do the migration would be better to go into specific solutions..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call a plugin method which is not supported on the Web platform (only on Android and/or iOS). Use Capacitor.isNativePlatform() to check if you can call the plugin method.

Comment: Thx a lot, it was indeed an plugin that I should have used. Basically, when starting the app I was using the `App.getInfo()` to search for the app version, but this made the app crashed, I went back to get it from the package.json file with this following code `version: require('../../package.json').version,` Chears